# Method for superluminal signal transfer - what's wrong?

Tags: special-relativity

Consider two starships on the opposite sides of the Milky Way. One of them is the sender S of the signal, and the other is the receiver R.

Let them both be stationary relative to each other, but moving at a speed close to the speed of light with respect to the galaxy. In their frame, the galaxy is contracted - say, to the width of 1 light second. Then in their frame a light signal sent by S to R arrives at destination in one second.

Starships' capitans agreed in advance that after this 1 second they will slow down uniformly, both at the same rate (same proper acceleration), to rest with respect to the galaxy. However, after they have slowed down they still remain a width of a galaxy apart - with a signal between them having travelled the whole width of the Milky Way in one second!

I understand that the people on Earth (at rest in the galaxy's frame) observe the signal travel the whole Milky Way. Now, because time is dilated for the starships, it runs so slow that indeed on the capitans' clocks (as viewed by Earthlings) it only takes one second to for the light sent to arrive at R. In that case, for the poor earthlings, millennia will have passed as the signal goes and goes along. Just like in Planet of the Apes.

But, from starships' perspective, time is dilated on Earth. So after they halt and compare their clocks (where 1s has passed plus the slowing-down time) with the Earth's clocks, it should appear to them like the whole signal sending procedure took literally femtoseconds. And they got their signal across the galaxy.

...right?

**What is wrong?**

Comment: You breeze past the whole "decelerating" part as though it was not there. But it's very important...

Comment: I haven't thought about it enough to be sure, but I'm pretty convinced @Floris has a point. An interesting side note would be to read the sci-fi book [Tau Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau_Zero) whose plot (without giving away too much) deals with deceleration. It's quite "hard" science fiction, but if you have a backing in Relativity, I think you'll find it rather captivating.

Comment: Well, I thought the whole clock hypothesis thing was that the clocks dilate according to instantaneous velocity. In the light of that I don't see why deceleration matters as the ship would have just seen the clock on Earth speed up from reaaaaly slow to normal. Not pass billions of years in the meantime.

Comment: Well, deceleration clearly does matter. It's the reason that the "twin paradox" [is not really a paradox](https://www.cpp.edu/~ajm/materials/twinparadox.html). I'm a bit rusty, so I might be wrong, but I fail to see the problem in spite of that: what information has been passed faster than the speed of light? The captains of the ships don't see a signal being superluminal because of length contraction, and the people on Earth wouldn't because of time dilation. The "1 second" of the captain would clearly not be a "1 second" for the Earthlings, as you've pointed out...

Comment: @Cherian and it indeed should be so, that nothing has been passed at superluminal speed. The problem arises in the next paragraph: for starship's crew, when they come back home to Earth, the whole procedure appears even quicker in Earth's time - because for them during the signal transfer mission the clocks on Earth were slowed down as the signal was being transferred.

Comment: No, as they decelerate the clocks on Earth will be seen running faster, same as in the twin's paradox. When they compare the clocks with the Earthlings after they stopped, the Earth's clock will actually indicate planet of the apes time.

Comment: Time dilation is due to velocity, not acceleration, right? During deceleration the velocity is non-zero and decreasing. This means that from starships' perspective the clocks on Earth are all the time dilated but their rates speed up from slow to normal. I don't see why would deceleration cause "time contraction" that is necessary for the clocks to match as in @Willy's comment.

Comment: you are incorrect, if you  want to learn read thishttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox

Answer (score -1):

> However, after they have slowed down they still remain a galaxy far
>   away - with a signal between them having travelled the whole width of
>   the Milky Way in one second!

No, both observe the distance between them increasing during their deceleration.

It is (or should be by now) well known that the two spacecraft cannot have the same uniform proper acceleration while maintaining constant (ruler, radar, etc.) distance.

Put another way, for uniformly accelerated observers to maintain constant distance, *their proper accelerations cannot be the same*.

From the Wikipedia article [Rindler coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates#A_.22paradoxical.22_property):

> Note that Rindler observers with smaller constant x coordinate are
>   accelerating harder to keep up! This may seem surprising because in
>   Newtonian physics, observers who maintain constant relative distance
>   must share the same acceleration. But in relativistic physics, we see
>   that the trailing endpoint of a rod which is accelerated by some
>   external force (parallel to its symmetry axis) must accelerate a bit
>   harder than the leading endpoint, or else it must ultimately break.

Comment: But that's not the point. The distance increases, but they are still **width of the galaxy apart** - the distance between the two is the width of the galaxy in their frame, which obviously changes with their velocity. When the send the signal, this distance is 1 light second, and after they have decelerated, it has already increased to 100,000 light years.

Comment: @xletmjm, it would appear then that you're playing word games than asking a serious question.

Comment: I am really sorry if you have such impression. It is a serious question, but the phrasing is awkward as there is nobody but you to interpret the question otherwise than I do to point out the things that are not clear in the phrasing.